# How to select only a small part of endorsers in hyperledger fabric endorsement policy

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am trying to develop a Dapp which would have only one channel between all the organisations. In a use case, there will be 1000 organisations, all connected to the same channel.

Now in the endorsement policy, all the endorsement peers in the organisations would need to  give endorsement for the transaction. If my use case, if only 20 endorsers endorse the transaction it would be fine. There is no point to get endorsement from all the organisations.

Is it possible to make a endorsement policy which would randomly select these 20 endorsers and proceed with the transaction flow.
In addition to this, though only 20 organisations endorsed it, eventually all the committers and endorsers should get the block from orderer and commit it to thier blockchain.

I am aware of outOf(20, org1, org2,......org1000) can be used so that only 20 will be considered but such a long comand would become impractical and why to ping all the organisations if only 20 are required(considering some down time maybe 40-50 to be sure). Cant just the requirednumber of organisations be pinged randomly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have already answered your own question.

An [endorsement policy](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.4/endorsement-policies.html#endorsement-policy-syntax) of `OutOf(20, org1, org2, ..., org1000)` would require endorsement from any 20 of the listed organisations. Once endorsements are obtained from peers of 20 organisations, no other organisations need to be contacted, and the endorsed transaction can be submitted to the orderer and distributed to all peers in the network. Note that only one peer from each of the 20 organisations needs to endorse.

Given a network with 1000 organisations (and provided there are sufficient orderers available), you should be able to have up to 980 organisations down or otherwise uncontactable, and still successfully submit transactions.